# Can't get Page Object Model to work with Appium, Serenity, Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium, appium, serenity-bdd

I am writing a selenium test automation framework using Java with Appium and Serenity.

I am having problems creating Page Object Model.

My page class looks like this:

```
public class MattVerifyPage extends PageObject{
private AppiumDriver driver;

public MattVerifyPage(AppiumDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
}


@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "Androidxpath")
@iOSFindBy(xpath = "iOSxpath")
public MobileElement verifyTitle ;


public void verifyTitle(String expectedTitle){

    String actualTitle =verifyTitle.getText();
}
```

In my test step file the page is instantiated using this code:

```
MattVerifyPage VerifyPage = new MattVerifyPage(driver);
```

However, when I run the test I get the error shown below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field com.xxx.test.pages.MattVerifyPage.verifyTitle to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:117)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.SmartElementProxyCreator.lambda$new$3(SmartElementProxyCreator.java:37)
at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.SmartElementProxyCreator.proxyElements(SmartElementProxyCreator.java:48)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DefaultPageObjectInitialiser.apply(DefaultPageObjectInitialiser.java:21)
at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.setDriver(PageObject.java:151)
at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.setDriver(PageObject.java:155)
at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.updatePageObject(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:69)
at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.instantiatePageObjectIfNotAssigned(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:59)
at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.injectDependenciesInto(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:33)
at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.injectDependenciesInto(Serenity.java:61)
at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.initializeWithNoStepListener(Serenity.java:102)
at cucumber.runtime.SerenityObjectFactory.newInstance(SerenityObjectFactory.java:68)
at cucumber.runtime.SerenityObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(SerenityObjectFactory.java:51)
at cucumber.runtime.SerenityObjectFactory.getInstance(SerenityObjectFactory.java:41)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runFeature(Runtime.java:119)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:104)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: Maybe the variable and method have the same name could be causing this. Change one and check if it works.

Comment: Your page object extends a class called PageObject.  Please include that code in your original post.  It's not your error, but your verifyTitle method does nothing.  Finally, perhaps you need the time parameter: `PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15)), this);`

Comment: problem is with public void verifyTitle(String expectedTitle){

    String actualTitle =verifyTitle.getText();
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Serenity BDD you shouldn't need to declare or manage your own WebDriver instance - Serenity will take care of that for you. There are many people on https://serenity-bdd.rocket.chat who do a lot of work with Serenity and Appium.

Comment: Thanks John I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For info it was the 'extends PageObject' that was causing the problem.
This is the Serenity PageObject.
For the time being I removed this and the Appium Page Object Model code then worked.